# How do you create a Handlebars block helper in Ember that can wrap/manipulate content?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js, ember-cli

I want to create a Handlebars block helper (to use in an Ember app) that wraps and escapes content. I thought it would be relatively simple, but I've spent hours on it and gotten nowhere. I want this:

```
{{#code}}
  <p>Hey!</p>
{{/code}}
```

To become this:

```
<pre>
  <code>
    &lt;p&gt;Hey!&lt;/p&gt;
  </code>
</pre>
```

The closest I've been able to get is this:

```
Em.Handlebars.registerHelper('code', function(options) {
  options.fn()
})
```

But that just outputs the content in the block straight away. I can't wrap it or manipulate it. Am I missing something obvious? Surely this can't be as difficult as it seems.

Comment: I already read the guide. The example is for a non-block helper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Custom helper would probably have to rely on private API which changes quite frequently in Ember - specially now as Glimmer rendering engine is being introduced. You will be probably better off with just using `Ember.Component`, using `{{yield}}` to render html into some hidden container, and then using `didInsertElement` hook to manipulate DOM manually using jQuery, e.g.

x-code.hbt

```
<div class="to-escape" style="display: none">{{yield}}</div>
<pre>
  <code>        
  </code>
</pre>
```

x-code.js

```
App.XCodeComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
  didInsertElement: function() {
    var value = this.$('.to-escape').html();
    this.$('code').text(value);
  }
});
```

and use it as

```
{{#x-code}}
  <p>Hey!</p>
{{/x-code}}
```

Example [JsBin](http://jsbin.com/jivetuyisa/1/edit?html,css,js,output).

Comment: Doing it as a component with `yield` would be acceptable if there was some way to manipulate the content in addition to just wrapping it, but I don't believe there is. I think it has to be a helper.

Comment: What about something like this: http://jsbin.com/xeyagulici/1/ ? There is however deprecation warning on current canary, I have to figure out how to do this properly in latest version of Ember...

Comment: I guess that would work as a last resort, although it's really janky :( I'm new-ish to Ember/Handlebars—is there a reason this is so difficult to do?

Comment: I [simplified it quite a bit](http://output.jsbin.com/yacenikino/1/edit?html,css,js,output); I was able to remove all the markup from the component.

Comment: The underlying reason is that Ember does many things for you auto-magically (e.g. automatically updating DOM based on the property changes). This however brings quite much complexity into underlying infrastructure. The main issue is that the rendering engine is undergoing significant refactoring from Ember 1.0 -> 2.0; While public API is backward compatible, private API and behaviour can change significantly  from version to version, making it very difficult to keep helpers that alter DOM rendering up-to-date...This will hopefully change as we hit Ember 2.0 (this summer)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78354/discussion-between-jesenko-and-brandon-weiss).

Comment: Ok .. how about now? I'm building a [declarative "table" tool](https://github.com/shaunc/ember-grid) with the idea that the user declares what handlebars fragments they want to use for types of cells, then we render in a two-dimentional grid. But we don't want the user to have to "write" the grid -- we want to capture the fragments and rerender them in "each" blocks. Where should I look for the interface for this?